# Remover números e caracteres especias de um texto, mas não dentro de uma palavra

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

Gostaria de remover números e/ou caracteres especiais de um texto, mas não dentro de uma palavra. Exemplo:

```
texto = "ol@ mundo, eu bebo H20 e nao fumo cig@rro !#& 123"
```

O resultado deve ser:

> ```
> ol@ mundo, eu bebo H20 e não fumo cig@rro
> ```

Código:

```
import re

texto = "ol@ mundo, eu bebo H20 e nao fumo cig@rro !#& 123"
resultado = re.sub(r"[^\w\s]", " ", texto)

print(resultado)
```

Output:

> ```
> ol  mundo  eu bebo H20 e nao fumo cig rro     123
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma alternativa é usar [*lookarounds*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
resultado = re.sub(r"(?<!\w)([^\w\s]|\d)+(?!\w)", " ", texto)
```

`(?<!\w)` é um *lookbehind* negativo que verifica se antes **não** tem um `\w`, e `(?!\w)` é um *lookahead* negativo que verifica se depois **não** tem um `\w`.

Entre eles eu também uso [alternância](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) (o `|`, que significa "ou") para que ele pegue também números (pois o `\w` também pega números, e ao negá-lo com `[^`, você também estava excluindo os números da substituição).

Também uso o quantificador `+` (uma ou mais ocorrências), para um ou mais caracteres que sejam `[^\w\s]` ou `\d`. Ou seja, a regex pega esses caracteres, desde que antes e depois não tenha um `\w` (letras, números ou `_`).

---

Você também poderia fazer `split()` como a outra resposta indicou, o problema é que se a string tiver separadores diferentes de espaço (como quebras de linha, TAB, ou até mesmo mais de um espaço), todos eles serão trocados por um espaço.

Uma alternativa com `split` é usar [grupos de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), pois assim os separadores também são retornados:

```
def substituir(s):
    if re.match(r'^\s+$', s): # se é separador, não substitui
        return s
    return re.sub(r'^[\W\d]+$', '', s)

resultado = ''.join(map(substituir, re.split(r'(\s+)', texto)))
```

O `split` é feito por `\s+` (um ou mais espaços, TAB's, quebras de linha, etc). Como está entre parênteses, isso forma um grupo de captura e esses separadores também são retornados.

Depois basta passar cada parte resultante do `split` para a função `substituir`, que não faz nada caso seja um separador, e remove os casos indesejados (`\W` é "tudo que não é `\w`", e `\d` pega os números). Também uso os [marcadores](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^` e `$`, que indicam respectivamente o início e fim da string, garantindo que só vou substituir quando a "palavra" inteira tem os caracteres indesejados. Caso a palavra seja válida, ela  não corresponderá à regex, e neste caso ela é retornada sem modificação.

Comment: Muito bom! Obrigado pela resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Como uma alternativa a outra resposta:

Você pode tentar separar por palavras antes, com um split, e realizar a regex em cada elemento:

```
import re
texto = "ol@ mundo, eu bebo H20 e nao fumo cig@rro !#& 123"
palavras = texto.split()

palavras = [re.sub(r"[^\w\s]", "", palavra) 
    if not re.sub(r"[^\w\s]", "", palavra) 
    else palavra
    for palavra in palavras] 
print(" ".join(palavras)) #imprime "ol@ mundo, eu bebo H20 e nao fumo cig@rro  123"
```

Se a palavra não tiver caracteres (`if not re.sub(r"[^\w\s]", "", palavra)`) após a substituição significa que ela deve ser substituida, se não, usar a palavra original.